# Convert Fri 01-11-2013 to Date Format in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

my date format is Fri 01-11-2013 which is text, i want to convert it to date and apply sorting on it. please help

Answer (score 0):

Currently I dont have the crystal reports tool with me to give exact solution but can provide you with below idea:

1. Extract `01-11-2013` from the string using right function like `Right("Fri 01-11-2013",10)`
2. Now use `Cdate` function to convert to date.
   `CDate(Right("Fri 01-11-2013",10))`

Note: This is not tested code

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CDate( Split("Fri 01-11-2013", " ")[2] )
```

You might also consider a regular expression, if your database supports it.